# OctoberCMS news list / detail page

Tags: php, octobercms

After programming plain HTML/CSS/Javascript/PHP I've just started using the CMS called OctoberCMS since both the Laravel framework and OctoberCMS look very well structured and easy to use/maintain. But I'm a little confused on how to process a single detail page or a overview page.

Let's take a news page for example. So far I've made this page:

```
title = "News"
url = "/news/:news_id?|^[0-9]+$"
layout = "default"
description = "This is the news page."
is_hidden = "0"
meta_title = "News"
meta_description = "News page meta description"
==
<?php
function onStart()
{
    $news_id = $this->param('news_id');
    if(isset($news_id)) {
        $news_article = []; //get the news article by id
        $this['news_article'] = $news_article;
    } else {
        $news = []; //get an array of news articles (last ... articles ordered by datetime desc)
        $this['news'] = $news;
    }
}
?>
==
<div class="container">
    <h1 class="block-title">
        News
    </h1>
    {% if news_article is defined %}
        Article
    {% else %}
        Overview
    {% endif %}
</div>
```

But where do I actually manage to make some sort of library for my news articles? I've read something about creating a new class in a new plug-in but I can't find any tutorials or documentation for this problem, or I'm just using the wrong terms while searching.  Can someone make a small example (maybe with news articles) or post a link where I can find a tutorial/documentation?

Answer (score 1):

That is more comfortable to use plugin instead for write all code yourself.

[Rain lab plugin](http://octobercms.com/plugin/rainlab-blog) allow create, manage, categorize, edit all kinds articles (include news).

You can get admin part from that plugin and use your visitor view.

Answer (score 1):

Documentation: https://octobercms.com/docs/plugin/registration

If you want to generate some code in command line here are some useful commands:

Generate plugin registration file and folders

```
php artisan create:plugin AuthorName.PluginName
```

Generate model

```
php artisan create:model AuthorName.PluginName ModelName
```

Generate controller

```
php artisan create:controller AuthorName.PluginName ModelNames
```

Refresh (reinstall) plugin

```
php artisan plugin:refresh AuthorName.PluginName
```

This should get you going, docs will be helpful after that.

Answer (score 1):

Use Builder (https://octobercms.com/plugin/rainlab-builder) plugin to manage CRUD very easily.

Suppose you have a model named NewsModel and you want to show the news listing or a single news in the frontend then you can modify your code by the following..

N.B: No need to write php opening and closing tag in the php section, just write

```
use Namespace\Plugin\Models\NewsModel; //needed to get data through model
function onStart()
{
    $news_id = $this->param('news_id');
    if($news_id) {
        $news_article = []; //get the news article by id
        $this['news_article'] = $news_article;
    } else {
        $news = []; //get an array of news articles (last ... articles ordered by datetime desc)
        $this['news_list'] = $news;
    }
}
==
<div class="container">    
    {% if news_article %}
        <h1 class="block-title"> News Details</h1>
        <div>{{ news_article.details }}</div> <!--Suppose you have a field named 'details' in the news table -->
    {% elseif news_list %}
        <h1 class="block-title"> News List</h1>
        <ul>
        {% for news in news_list %}
           <li> {{ news.title }}</li><!--Suppose you have a field named 'title' in the news table -->
        {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    {% else %}
        No news found !
    {% endif %}
</div>
```