# OctoberCMS Builder Plugin to Show Data on Front End

Tags: laravel-5, octobercms

This my first time to use OctoberCMS, and they provide the [Builder Plugin](http://octobercms.com/plugin/rainlab-builder) in order to help the developer builds plugin in minutes.

I try to use this plugin to show the data on the front end especially when using `Components > Builder > Record list`, but the documentation didn't give enough example to get data from some fields.  The example on the internet is just show how to get the data from one field.

My code is shown below:

```
[builderList]
modelClass = "Budiprasetyo\Employees\Models\Employee"
scope = "-"
displayColumn = "name"
noRecordsMessage = "No records found"
detailsPage = "-"
detailsUrlParameter = "id"
pageNumber = "{{ :page }}"
```

in my case, I want to get the data not only `"name"` field, but I also want to add `"email", "facebook"` fields.

I have tried to make it into:

```
displayColumn = "name", "email", "facebook"
```

but it returns no data shown and I have tried to make it into array:

```
displayColumn = ["name", "email", "facebook"]
```

and it's the same result, no data is shown.

I appreciate any helps, thank you.

Comment: You can look at the following link, It might be some help of you.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/58623382/1388178

Answer (score 2):

Actually I don't like to use plugins' components. Sometimes it doesn't retrieve any data. I don't know why maybe it's just because of wrong using.
Anyway, The best way to retrieve the data from your plugin is to navigate to the code section and then write `onStart()` function and start to retrieve to data.

```
function onStart()
{
$data = \Authorname\Pluginname\Models\Model::find(1);
$this['data'] = $data;
}
```

And this way you'll have a `data` variable in the markup section.

Answer (score 0):

On the frontend cms page, you need to replace the component call with your custom partial. Your partial file should look something like this:

*podcastList is the component name

```
{% set records =podcastList.records %}
{% set displayColumn =podcastList.displayColumn %}
{% set noRecordsMessage =podcastList.noRecordsMessage %}
{% set detailsPage =podcastList.detailsPage %}
{% set detailsKeyColumn =podcastList.detailsKeyColumn %}
{% set detailsUrlParameter =podcastList.detailsUrlParameter %}

{% for record in records %}
  <span class="date">{{ attribute(record, 'date') }}</span>
  <span class="title">{{ attribute(record, 'title') }}</span>
  <p>{{ attribute(record, 'description') }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Obviously, this is simplified version, but you get the point. You can easily define more columns without touching the page component settings.